# How to append a value to list attribute on AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm using DynamoDB as an K-V db (cause there's not much data, I think that's fine) , and part of 'V' is list type (about 10 elements). There's some session to append a new value to it, and I cannot find a way to do this in 1 request. What I did is like this:

```
item = self.list_table.get_item(**{'k': 'some_key'})
item['v'].append('some_value')
item.partial_save()
```

I request the server first and save it after modified the value. That's not atomic and looks ugly. Is there any way to do this in one request?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The following code should work with boto3:

```
table = get_dynamodb_resource().Table("table_name")
result = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'hash_key': hash_key,
        'range_key': range_key
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET some_attr = list_append(some_attr, :i)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i': [some_value],
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
if result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200 and 'Attributes' in result:
    return result['Attributes']['some_attr']
```

The get_dynamodb_resource method here is just:

```
def get_dynamodb_resource():
    return boto3.resource(
            'dynamodb',
            region_name=os.environ['AWS_DYNAMO_REGION'],
            endpoint_url=os.environ['AWS_DYNAMO_ENDPOINT'],
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
            aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'])
```

Comment: thank you! this works perfectly. Although i tried using ADD but that did not work. I read in the docs that they recommend using ADD. When i tried to use ADD, i got operator mismatch Error in UpdateExression.

Comment: Very useful! Sorry i can only do +1 :(

Comment: does the list item have to exist? or can I just use this and it'll init some_attr for me as an empty list if it did not exist?

Comment: If you need to create a list if it's not exist, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951043/is-it-possible-to-combine-if-not-exists-and-list-append-in-update-item

Comment: Totally with vnpnlz on this (am also sorry I can only do +1).

Comment: Is this best practise? I'm asking in terms of capacity units. I'm appending a very tiny object to a list, but writing capacity is calculated based on whole item size. What should I do if I want to append 50byte to a 300kb item? Do I have to pay writing capacity of 300 kb?

Comment: it work for me when i created record in dynamodb like this but i have differrent ID:
```
item = {'ID':  user_id, 'Keys_API': [ "empty list" ] }
                table.put_item(
                    TableName=table_name,
                    Item=item
                )

```
First time i was wrong which got me trouble i used this way which is not working but above code worked:

```
item = {'ID':  user_id, 'Keys_API':{ "L":  ["new created"] }  }
                table.put_item(
                    TableName=table_name,
                    Item=item
                )

```
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can do this in 1 request by using the [`UpdateItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) API in conjunction with an [`UpdateExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression). Since you want to append to a list, you would use the `SET` action with the `list_append` function:

> `SET` supports the following functions:
>
> ...
>
> - `list_append (operand, operand)` - evaluates to a list with a new
>     element added to it. You can append the new element to the start or
>     the end of the list by reversing the order of the operands.

You can see a couple examples of this on the [Modifying Items and Attributes with Update Expressions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html):

> - The following example adds a new element to the *FiveStar* review list.
>     The expression attribute name `#pr` is *ProductReviews*; the attribute
>     value `:r` is a one-element list. If the list previously had two
>     elements, `[0]` and `[1]`, then the new element will be `[2]`.
>
>   ```
>   SET #pr.FiveStar = list_append(#pr.FiveStar, :r)
>   ```
> - The following example adds another element to the *FiveStar* review
>     list, but this time the element will be appended to the start of the
>     list at `[0]`. All of the other elements in the list will be shifted by
>     one.
>
>   ```
>   SET #pr.FiveStar = list_append(:r, #pr.FiveStar)
>   ```

The `#pr` and `:r` are using placeholders for the attribute names and values. You can see more information on those on the [Using Placeholders for Attribute Names and Values documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would look at update expressions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.ADD

Should be doable with an ADD, although not sure what the support in boto is for this.

Answer (score 1):

@LaserJesus 's answer is correct. However, using boto3 directly is kind of a pain, hard to maintain, and not at all reusable. [dynamof](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof) abstracts that junk away. Using `dynamof` appending an item to a list attribute would look like:

```
from functools import partial
from boto3 import client
from dynamof.executor import execute
from dynamof.operations import update
from dynamof.attribute import attr

client = client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localstack:4569')
db = partial(execute, client)

db(update(
  table_name='users',
  key={ 'id': user_id },
  attributes={
      'roles': attr.append('admin')
  }))
```

*disclaimer: I wrote dynamof*