# Is it possible to combine if_not_exists and list_append in update_item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to use the `update_item` functionality for DynamoDB in boto3.

I'm struggling right now to update lists for items. I would like to create a new list if the list does not exist yet and otherwise append to the existing list.

Using an `UpdateExpression` of the form `SET my_list = list_append(my_list, :my_value)` returns an error *"The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item"* if the list does not exist yet.

Any idea how I would have to modify my `UpdateExpression`?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can use `list_append(if_not_exists())` construction.

UpdateExpression:

```
'SET my_list2 = list_append(if_not_exists(my_list2, :empty_list), :my_value)'
```

ExpressionAttributeValues:

```
{ ":my_value":{"L": [{"S":"test"}]}, ":empty_list":{"L":[]} }
```

**Update**: as mentioned in the comments, boto3 now raises an error for the expression above and a version without explicit types works: `{ ":my_value": ["test"], ":empty_list":[] }`.

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is subject to race-conditions? I'm looking over the AWS documentation, and they don't seem to have any locking/transactions (at least for the Python SDK). It certainly seems like this code could a: read the list from the DB, b: append the new value, and c: overwrite the old value, which _could_ have been changed in the meantime.

Comment: I can't find a direct confirmation in the documentation, but I would expect single UpdateItem operation to be atomic, the closest thing I found in faq - "You can increment or decrement a numeric attribute in a row using a single API call. Similarly, you can atomically add or remove to sets, lists, or maps", see https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

Comment: Hi I am struggling to reproduce the answer. `{ 
    "TableName": "WishboxUsers",
    "Key": {
     "uid": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "SET my_list2 = list_append(if_not_exists(my_list2, :empty_list), :my_value)",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":my_value":[{"S":"test"}],
             ":empty_list":[]
    }
}` Can you help me? Are there different versions of the DynamoDB API? How can I change them? I get the response: `"Unrecognized collection type class com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810.AttributeValue"`

Comment: @csikos.balint I think the problem is not with the expression, but with something else - I've just tired with DynamoDB local and the example works, complete set of parameters: `{ TableName: 'my_table',
    Key: { my_key: 'hash1' }, UpdateExpression: 'SET my_list2 = list_append(if_not_exists(my_list2, :empty_list), :my_value)', ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":my_value":[{"S":"test"}], ":empty_list":[] } };`. Initially I have "my_table" defined with one "my_key" hash field. So it's better if you post your problem as a separate question with complete code example.

Comment: @aidinism I think you misunderstood the question and the answer. It is not about preventing the duplicate values, the question was "how to create a new list if the list does not exist yet and otherwise append to the existing list.".

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion! I got it working for my project here if anyone interested: https://github.com/networth-app/networth/blob/f79f2c8d55b2614a09465331cf9b360c31d0bb1f/api/lib/dynamodb.go#L155

Comment: I had to set my `ExpressionAttributeValues` to

    `{":my_value": {"L": [{"S": "test"}]}, ":empty_list": {"L": []}}`

for anyone that runs into the same problem as me.

Comment: for me "':empty_list': []" was sufficient (no need for "L")

Comment: Perhaps something has changed since this answer was given, but using Python/Flask and this code would throw exceptions about me trying to pass a map to list_append. I think boto3 dynamically determines the type now? Anyway. Changing the ExpressionAttributeValues to `{ ":my_value": ["test"], ":empty_list":[] }` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Tom thanks! The other example did not work for me and caused type errors. The pure brackets did the trick. Maybe that is the way python/boto3 expects it.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to Boris solution could be to use [set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) instead of list datatype and use the ADD keyword, it does exactly what you want.

With Add, the update expression becomes: `ADD setName :s`

And the expression attribute values can be like: `{":s": {"SS":["First", "Second"]}}`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD

Comment: Note that "The order of the values within a set is not preserved" so if you want an `ordered collection` then you want a List. Your expression example is misleading because `["First", "Second"]` could easily be returned as `["Second", "First"]`. The benefit of set is that it contains no duplicates. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

Comment: I like this solution. Just adding note that the `set` type can only contain scalar elements (so no sets of `map` type)