# How to append elements to a list in DynamoDB using Rust

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-rust

I'm struggling using [list_append](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) programmatically in Rust.

I have a table called `Humidities`:

```
{
 "id": 177,
 "Measurements": [
  49
 ]
}
```

and I want to add elements. For example:

```
{
 "id": 177,
 "Measurements": [
  49,
  53
 ]
}
```

This is a working solution for python, which I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288085/how-to-append-a-value-to-list-attribute-on-aws-dynamodb) :

```py
table = get_dynamodb_resource().Table("table_name")
result = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'hash_key': hash_key,
        'range_key': range_key
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET some_attr = list_append(some_attr, :i)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i': [some_value],
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
if result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200 and 'Attributes' in result:
    return result['Attributes']['some_attr']
```

Based on the python solution I've tried this:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let Opt { base } = Opt::from_args();
    let shared_config = make_config(base).await?;
    let client = Client::new(&shared_config);
    client
        .update_item()
        .table_name("Humidities")
        .key("id", AttributeValue::N(177.to_string()))
        .update_expression("SET i = list_append(Measurements, :i)")
        .expression_attribute_values("i", AttributeValue::N(53.to_string()))
        .send()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

However, the result is:

```
Error: Unhandled(Error { code: Some("ValidationException"), message: Some("ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \"i\""), request_id: Some("05RSFGFJEEDPO7850LI2T91RGRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG"), extras: {} })
```

What am I doing wrong?

The examples only demonstrate how to add a single item: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust/blob/main/examples/dynamodb/src/bin/add-item.rs

I've also tried this:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let Opt { base } = Opt::from_args();
    let shared_config = make_config(base).await?;
    let client = Client::new(&shared_config);
    client
        .update_item()
        .table_name("Humidities")
        .key("id", AttributeValue::N(177.to_string()))
        .update_expression("set #Measurements = list_append(#Measurements, :value)")
        .expression_attribute_names("#Measurements", "Measurements")
        .expression_attribute_values("value", AttributeValue::N(53.to_string()))
        .return_values(aws_sdk_dynamodb::model::ReturnValue::AllNew)
        .send()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

with a look at: [Append a new object to a JSON Array in DynamoDB using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400538/append-a-new-object-to-a-json-array-in-dynamodb-using-nodejs)

Same result, value is unknown:

```
Error: Unhandled(Error { code: Some("ValidationException"), message: Some("ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \"value\""), request_id: Some("1A8VEOEVSB7LMAB47H12N7IKC7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG"), extras: {} })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. There have been two problems:

- list_append expects two lists
- expression_attribute_values expected `:value` instead of `value`

Running example:

```rust
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let Opt { base } = Opt::from_args();
    let shared_config = make_config(base).await?;
    let client = Client::new(&shared_config);
    client
        .update_item()
        .table_name("Humidities")
        .key("id", AttributeValue::N(177.to_string()))
        .update_expression("set #Measurements = list_append(#Measurements, :value)")
        .expression_attribute_names("#Measurements", "Measurements")
        .expression_attribute_values(
            ":value", // changed from "value" to ":value"
            AttributeValue::L(vec![AttributeValue::N(53.to_string())]), // use a vector of numbers instead of a number
        )
        .return_values(aws_sdk_dynamodb::model::ReturnValue::AllNew)
        .send()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```